# how much data can javascript in the browser hold?

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a JSFiddle to see how much data I can push into my browser.

The link is http://jsfiddle.net/GWxAk/

The code is simple. It's just trying to push as many strings as possible into an array. 
The strings have an approximate length of 300-310 characters.

My question is: 
does the result depend on how much memory I have got on my PC ?
does it really differ browser to browser ?

For instance if I have 8gb of ram will I get much more then if I have 4gb ?

```
var s = '';
for (var i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
    s += 'a';
}

array = [];
count = 0;

function doMore() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        count++;
        array.push(s + count);
    }
};

function repeat() {
    doMore();
    document.body.innerHTML = 'size:' + array.length;
    setTimeout(repeat, 100);
}

repeat();
```

In my case  chrome hangs at 14850000 and I have 4gb of ram
That is an array of almost 15 million items. Not bad I guess

Do you guys get the same ?
Can somebody tell how to give as much memory as possible to the browser

Thanks

Comment: Have you got a real life situation for this, or are you just bored at work?

Comment: I have 16GB of RAM on my machine and I got to a point slightly over double where you did. You can see my results in the screenshot here http://screencast.com/t/3Xl31yGgHWC

Comment: Looks like some kind of safety feature of the browser. Mine stops at the same number even though it hasn't been any strain whatsoever on the machine. With Chrome and 16GB RAM.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript Memory Limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936782/javascript-memory-limit)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Again, my machine with 16GB of RAM. I can watch the browser RAM usage climb as it increases, so I would assume it's limited by RAM as well.

```
IE crapped out at 16,840,000
Chrome at 14,850,000
Firefox 32,890,000
Safari recycles itself around 8,720,000 (LOL @ Apple)
```

Here is a screenshot of memory usage and firefox http://screencast.com/t/3Xl31yGgHWC

Answer (score 5):

Lets assume UTF8, meaning your 'a' is 2 bytes/8bits.

- 14,850,000 * 300 = 4455000000 characters
- 14850000 * 300  * 2 = 8,910,000,000 bytes
- 8910000000 /1024 = 8,701,171.875 KB
- (8910000000 /1024 ) / 1024 = 8,497.238159179688 MB
- ((8910000000 /1024 ) / 1024 ) / 1024 = 8.298084139823914 GB

As such we can surmise from your test that the maximum length of a string in Chromes JS engine is 4,455,000,000 characters, or ~ 8.3 GB in memory.

But ofcourse this is not what's happening. You only have 4GB of RAM yet ~4298MB has appeared out of nowhere according to the figures, and there's the structures of the array variable itself and the java VM and chrome itself ot account for etc etc

Not to mention that you're pushing s+count not s on its own, so the length of the string being added is rising as the number of digits in count increases. If s was the same, then its likely the value would be interned to save memory by the V8 engine. For reference, the number of additional characters added because of the count variable, and due to it's non linear increase in length, is 9,7438,889 characters or 185.85MB of data.

So something else must be happening here.

As for the limits of the V8 JS engine:

http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=847

The 32bit memory address space is the upper limit, and for 64bit, that link suggest ~1.9GB although it's very much likely to be the upper limit of what your OS can support and is physically available.

So to summarise:

- 32bit will always be an upper bound, not of your specific js variable, but of the entire bundle of js VM, renderer, page contents, etc
- Your test is not quite reliable as the items it is counting are not identical
- If they were identical, you would fall foul of special case handling of strings

**edit:**

Comment: I add count to s to ensure that each string is different. My test is reliable because each item has to be unique.

Comment: not quite, the first item will be 1 character shorter than the 11th, which will be one character shorter than the 101st which will be one character shorter than the 1001st etc, as such the number at the very end is not counting units of equal size ( regardless of contents ), as the final string added to the array, is much larger than the initial string.

Comment: e.g. my van contains 50 doghnuts and yours contains 20 dognuts, is a meaningless comparison if the dognuts are not of equal size

Comment: what's more count is an number, and hence a 64bit float, and is subject to the inherent fuzziness of floating point values as the number gets higher

Comment: I don't get why you get bogged down into the fact that the first string is 300 chars long the 11th 301 and the string no. 12543 is 305 characters long. As said that's just to ensure that we don't reuse any of the previous ones.

Comment: Because the strings are no longer of equal length and size, and since your question concerns the quantity of strings you can store, the size is the whole point. If you prefixed your strings with zeros then this test would be much fairer and balanced.

Comment: But at the moment, the number of strings you have is not a reliable number since 10 more strings at 200 is not the same as 10 more strings at 2000, and that difference can add up to a sizeable difference as you iterate.

Comment: Think of it this way, you're buying bricks, and your van can only hold so many, what is the maximum number that it will hold? Your test introduces the concept that as you put more bricks in the van, the bricks themselves get bigger, until you put the last brick in and it's twice the size of the first ( which is clearly wrong because you could have fit 2 in its place )

Answer (score 3):

I am ON Chrome and i tried your test and it hangs on the same 14850000 you mentioned even if i only have 2gb of ram and i am running a VM with windows inside my linux installation that i gave 700Mb of ram so i guess yes chrome has a limit

Comment: Until [very recently](http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=847), V8 (Chrome's JS engine) had a hard upper limit of 1 GB.  That's fixed, but the default limit is 700/1400 MB on 32/64-bit builds.

Answer (score 0):

On a 32-bit machine your upper limit will always be 4GB, no if ands or buts. In practice, it will be wildly different machine to machine (not unusual to have 10+ tabs open)

Best way to go: keep only the data your user is actively working on or anything you can't quickly retrieve from the server handy. Everything else, get when the user asks for it.

Comment: Actually, you will only be able to use about 2-3 GB of the 32-bit address space.  This also applies to 32-bit processes (which is may be why even on 16GB machines it stops so early).  Note: the array in this example not only requires a large amount of memory, it requires a large amount of contiguous memory!