# How much memory can I use in my JavaScript app in Browser?

Tags: javascript, memory, browser

I’m developing a JavaScript App (using React, Redux...).
My app need some metadata to work, to display objects in trees or in tables...

I’m just wondering if I should load all these metadata from the server in one shot and keep them in a memory or if I should perform each time requests to get only what I need to minimize the memory footprint.

My data are not so big, maybe 1 or 2 MB.

I wonder how much memory I can rely on in general in browser ?

What is the order of magnitude 10MB, 100MB, 1GB...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript memory limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936782/javascript-memory-limit)

Comment: Depends on your clients :)

Comment: You could use localStorage since the browser stores It on computer's disk

Answer (score 1):

There's no upper limit. However, being conservative in memory usage is smart. Nobody likes a hungry web application.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can use based on browser,but max you can check with these code in console

```
window.performance.memory.jsHeapSizeLimit
```

If you are using chrome 32 bit, then JS heap is limited to ~756MB