# Reading local large json file of size 30MB in react-native,

Tags: javascript, file, react-native, size

I am newbie on react-native. I am trying to read data from large json file placed in project directory. But my app crashed giving alert "Unfortunately Project has stopped", when build. I spent much time on searching online but unable to get proper information. How to do this task.

This is my file path "./msg/message.json"

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Button} from 'react-native';

var myMsg = require('./msg/message.json');

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native!</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>To get started, edit App.js</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>Text</Text>
        <Button title="Login"></Button>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: if you copy/paste the JSON as a local variable, does it also crash? Is it valid JSON?

Comment: Yes, It is valid JSON. I had also checked by reducing data from this file resulting to some Kb. Then it was working fine. But not working fine with large data.

Comment: sounds like you're hitting the limits of JS on your system

Comment: I do not understand by the limits of JS, Please guide me what to do.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936782/javascript-memory-limit

This is a better job for a server instead of a client.

Comment: i had a 30mb json file once, even reading that in my own PC was making me crazy, i'm not sure it's good idea to read that in your phone in the app(due to its heavy process)

Comment: If you really, absolutely need to parse this file, write a native module to handle it on another thread and then pass just the bits that you need to JS

Comment: you could create a sqllite database for it then query the data.